# Difference between using a ternary operator or just short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, short-circuiting

Recently came across short-circuit evaluation and was a little confused by it as i only got into programming the past week. From what i understand if what ever comes before the first double pipe is true then it will stop and not evaluate what comes after the double pipe. For Example:

**Example 1:**

```
var a = true;
var b = a || {};
```

So i assume if a exists then assign a to b otherwise b is equal to an object.
What i dont understand is where i will use this and how it differs to a ternary operator, isn't the short circuit evaluation the same as:

**Example 2:**

```
var a = true;
var b = (a) ? a : {};
```

Why would one use example 1 over example 2 as it isn't any slower to write out or is there a speed benefit of the use of one over the other? or is this just a silly question and perhaps i'm missing something. If someone could clear this up for me that would be great.

Comment: This only matters when the second operand has side-effects.

Comment: Use whichever one you want. The time you've already spent thinking about it will be greater than any cumulative difference in typing or execution.

Comment: Kinda unrelated, but as an experiment try doing `b = a && {};` and see what happens and try to understand why it happens.

Comment: @Ergwun Did you mean the *first* operand (`a`)?

Comment: @Bergi No, I was trying to say that short circuit evaluation behaviour is important when the second operand has side effect. See my answer below for an explanation.

Comment: @Ergwun It seems you are comparing a short-circuiting `&&` with a (hypothetical) strict `&&` operator, but that's no what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Bergi True. I've updated my answer to address the actual question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of your examples will result in `b` being assigned the value of `a` (`true`), and both constructs avoid the evaluation of the final operand (which is `{}` in each case).

However, there are differences in readability and evaluation.

**Readability:**

I'd argue that `if (a || b) { ... }` is more readable than `if (a ? a : b) { ... }`).

**Operand evaluation**:

In `(a || b)`, `a` is only evaluated once. In `(a ? a : b)`, `a` is evaluated twice. This becomes important when instead of a simple variable you are using an function or other expression:

```
// Costly double evaluation
var a = someExpensiveFunction()
    ? someExpensiveFunction()
    : {};

// Less costly single evaluation
var a = someExpensiveFunction() || {};
```

More generally, short circuit operators can help you:

- avoid errors by only evaluating the second operand when it is safe:

```
    var a = a && someFunctionThatWillThrowIfAIsNull(a);
```

- avoid slow functions under certain conditions by placing them as the second operand:

```
    // Slower
    var a = someSlowFunction() || someFastFunction();
    
    // Faster
    var a = someFastFunction() || someSlowFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example the different usages (depending on the first parameter). Check the console for each of them to understand the way they work.

```js
console.log("'' || {}:", '' || {});
console.log("1 || {}:", 1 || {});
console.log("0 || {}:", 0 || {});
console.log("true || {}:", true || {});
console.log("false || {}:", false || {});
console.log("[] || {}:", [] || {});

console.log('');

console.log("('') ? '' : {}:", ('') ? '' : {});
console.log("(1) ? 1 : {}:", (1) ? 1 : {});
console.log("(0) ? 0 : {}:", (0) ? 0 : {});
console.log("(true) ? true : {}:", (true) ? true : {});
console.log("(false) ? false : {}:", (false) ? false : {});
console.log("([]) ? [] : {}:", ([]) ? [] : {});

console.log('');

console.log("'' && {}:", '' && {});
console.log("1 && {}:", 1 && {});
console.log("0 && {}:", 0 && {});
console.log("true && {}:", true && {});
console.log("false && {}:", false && {});
console.log("[] && {}:", [] && {});
```

Comment: Thank you for the visual demo, i think i just didn't quite understand how short-circuiting worked but i have a better idea now, thank you.

Comment: There is an error in the code snippet. `console.log("([]) ? '' : {}:", ([]) ? [] : {});` should be `console.log("([]) ? [] : {}:", ([]) ? [] : {});`