# Short circuit evaluation with ternary output

Tags: javascript

I am using short circuit evaluation to assign some variables. I had to use a ternary operator in some of them, but it does not behave as I expected :

```js
console.log(false || "bar"); // Outputs "bar"
console.log("foo" || "bar"); // Outputs "foo"
console.log("foo" || (true) ? "42" : "bar"); // Ouputs "42", why ?
```

Shouldn't the third `console.log` output "foo" instead ?

Comment: Because `"foo" || (true)` is truthy - you need `console.log("foo" || (true ? "42" : "bar")); `

Comment: Operator precedence … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: because of operator precedence. jsu take a parenthesis for the condition part

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413519/difference-between-using-a-ternary-operator-or-just-short-circuit-evaluation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
console.log("foo" || (true) ? "42" : "bar"); // Ouputs "42", why ?
```

because it's being evaluated as

```
console.log(("foo" || true) ? "42" : "bar");
```

with `("foo" || true)` being evaluated first as a truthy value.

Your bracket is in the wrong place perhaps you meant

```
console.log("foo" || (true ? "42" : "bar"));
```