# Javascript SonarQube refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity

Tags: javascript, sonarlint

For below JavaScript function i am trying to figure out how to reduce the Cognitive Complexity.

```
function Person(data) {
    var self = this;
    if (data) {
        self.id = data.Id === null? "" : data.Id;
        self.name = data.Name === null? "" : data.Name;
        self.phone= data.Phone === null? "" : data.Phone;
        self.address = data.Address=== null ? "" : data.Address;
    } else {
        self.id = "";
        self.name = "";
        self.phone = "";
        self.address = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function Person(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = "";
    self.name = "";
    self.phone = "";
    self.address = "";

    if (data) {
        self.id = getValueOrDefault(data.Id);
        self.name = getValueOrDefault(data.Name);
        self.phone = getValueOrDefault(data.Phone);
        self.address = getValueOrDefault(data.Address);
    }
}

function getValueOrDefault(value) {
    return value === null ? "" : value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) along with [short-circuit operator](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-javascript-short-circuiting-operators).

With the optional chaining, you avoid calling to the parameters (Id, Name, Phone, Address) and return undefined directly. Then with the short-circuit operator you will pass the default value, in the case the left side returning a undefined.

```
function Person(data) {
  this.id = data?.Id || "";
  this.name = data?.Name || "";
  this.phone = data?.Phone || "";
  this.address = data?.Address || "";
}
```

More on why those are good options for legibility (which is related to Cognitive Complexity):

- [Difference between using a ternary operator or just short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413519/difference-between-using-a-ternary-operator-or-just-short-circuit-evaluation)
- [Using Optional Chaining and Nullish Coalescing Operator in JavaScript](https://matthewshields.co.uk/using-optional-chaining-and-nullish-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).